# Module data structure with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database-design, database

I'm about to start prototyping a small app using mongodb, but i'm having trouble working out the data structure for what i want to do with mongo.

Briefly, I want to be able to create a article type that modules can be assigned to (you could call them widgets). There are a set of module types with corresponding templates, and there can be multiple modules per article, but the data in each one will be different.

I've put a concept diagram together of how I think it could work, but if anyone could suggest a better alternative, would really appreciate it.

```
Article
-------
ARTICLE_ID: objectId
TITLE: string
DESCRIPTION: string
MODULES: [{module_id, position}]


Module Type
-----------
MODULE_TYPE_ID: objectId
MODULE_NAME: string
FIELDS: [{fieldName, fieldType}]
TEMPLATE_ID: objectId


Module
------
MODULE_ID: objectId
TITLE: string
MODULE_TYPE_ID: objectId
DATA: [field data here?]
```

Thanks all

Comment: does this three type has any connection between them

Comment: Because you can't do join with in mongo DB you have to do in with in your program and would have to show the result

Comment: Sorry if things aren't clear, I'm not the most experienced database designer - more a front end dev. The connection that I envision is the article can have multiple modules, the module holds the data for a populated module type, and is connected to that module type. does that make any sense?

Comment: So you want join in mongo which is not possible by mongo alone

Comment: As per their(mongoDB) development they did not provide join method because it is a document oriented database

Comment: If you are good at programming language you can keep it as seperate tables(collections in mongodb phrase) and do join by programming but it will increase the processing time if data is large

Comment: OR you could keep them in same table(collection) since there is no schema in mongo DB you are free to create your own schema but if join is not avoidable then join needs to be performed using any programming language and your logic